# How use the class MyBluetoothService in the Android bluetooth documentation

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I don't understand the best way to use this class that the official documentation expose.

They say

> 1)Get the InputStream and OutputStream that handle transmissions through
> the socket using getInputStream() and getOutputStream(), respectively.
>
> 2)Read and write data to the streams using read(byte[]) and
> write(byte[]).

and give this example

```
public class MyBluetoothService {
    private static final String TAG = "MY_APP_DEBUG_TAG";
    private Handler mHandler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service

    // Defines several constants used when transmitting messages between the
    // service and the UI.
    private interface MessageConstants {
        public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
        public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;

        // ... (Add other message types here as needed.)
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
            // member streams are final.
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
            }
            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream.
                    numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                    Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                            mmBuffer);
                    readMsg.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);

                // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
                Message writtenMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                        MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
                writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

                // Send a failure message back to the activity.
                Message writeErrorMsg =
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("toast",
                        "Couldn't send data to the other device");
                writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
            }
        }

        // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the rest of the code that following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp) in the main activity and i need to manage the connection now with this class...

Now i adapt the code in the main activity (copy the private class ConnectedThread extends Threads in the MainActivity) but if someone can explain to me the best usage of this class it's better for me.

Thanks